# Make powersave governor permanent

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, xfce

is there any option to make powersafe `cpufreq` governor permanent? Although i set default frequency to powersave, it automatically changes to other governor (in most cases "`ondemand`").

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During boot Ubuntu runs a script `/etc/init.d/ondemand` that waits one minute, then sets `ondemand` mode. You can make a change to that script such that it sets `powersave` mode instead.

Note that doing so, and with the acpi-cpufreq driver, your CPUs will always be at the very minimum clock frequency.

Comment: thanks, so if I change the value "`ondemand`" on `line 36` in `/etc/init.d/ondemand` to "`powersave` it will set this governor permanently? Just note that I did it and it works properly so far.

Comment: I am not aware of anything that would subsequently change it again. However, I am a server type and don't use desktop versions