# Make indicator-cpufreq startup with specified governor

Tags: 16.04, indicator, intel, cpu, cpufreq

I've installed `indicator-cpufreq`, everything works OK, but I faced the fact that only two governor states are available - `Perfomance` and `Powersave`(always set on startup). My attempts to make `Perfomance` as default always failed. Changing 'ondemand.d' script edit went fail (still loads "Powersafe" by default)

My CPU Specs: Core i7-3630QM 2.4Ghz 
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Thanks for suggestions

Update:
[Make powersave governor permanent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608778/make-powersave-governor-permanent) not working

Comment: Only two governor states are available because, by default, you are using the intel_pstate CPU frequency driver, which only has those two governors. With the intel_pstate CPU frequency driver the "powersave" governor is very roughly the same as the "ondemand" governor for the acpi-cpufreq CPU scaling driver. There is no reason i can think of that you can not set the "performance" governor, but then I do not use `indicator-cpufreq`.

Comment: I made `intel_pstate=disable` via Grub loader back then on 14.04, also schedule to run the command on startup (dont remember the rest of the cmd but it contained `cpufreq-selector` or so) and after that, all greatly worked...until i reinstalled ubuntu. So, there might be a chance to make back it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the question was the following: "How do I change/set the governor state used by indicator-cpufreq at startup/default".
So here is the solution which worked for me (Ubuntu 17.04):
edit /lib/systemd/set-cpufreq so that the the governor you want is used as the first case in the switch-section, i.e. just change the order of the cases. So if I want "powersave" at startup then I change /lib/systemd/set-cpufreq to look like this, notice the line

```
*powersave*)
```

right after the line

```
case $governors in
```

so here is the result:

```
#! /bin/sh
# Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand"/"powersave" where available
set -eu

FIRSTCPU=`cut -f1 -d- /sys/devices/system/cpu/online`
AVAILABLE="/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$FIRSTCPU/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors"
DOWN_FACTOR="/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/ondemand/sampling_down_factor"

[ -f $AVAILABLE ] || exit 0

read governors < $AVAILABLE
case $governors in
    *powersave*)
            GOVERNOR="powersave"
            break
            ;;
    *interactive*)
            GOVERNOR="interactive"
            break
            ;;
    *ondemand*)
            GOVERNOR="ondemand"
            case $(uname -m) in
                    ppc64*)
                            SAMPLING=100
                    ;;
            esac
            break
            ;;
    *)
            exit 0
            ;;
esac

[ -n "${GOVERNOR:-}" ] || exit 0

echo "Setting $GOVERNOR scheduler for all CPUs"

for CPUFREQ in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
do
    [ -f $CPUFREQ ] || continue
    echo -n $GOVERNOR > $CPUFREQ
done
if [ -n "${SAMPLING:-}" ] && [ -f $DOWN_FACTOR ]; then
    echo -n $SAMPLING > $DOWN_FACTOR
fi
```

Comment: Is ti just me or my CPU is so weird, but it doesnt work for me. Moreover, i have only powersaving and high perfomance profiles. If picking High perfomance, it may take sometimes to start programs longer than it used to be before. (hm, throttling?) and `systeminfo` shows that all cores are at max speed 3.7Ghz(because turbo boost is on)